# connect db and back using service name

Tags: consul, nomad, hashicorp

I try to use service name to connect my nomad job **Postgresql** and the **app**.
Using agent node where the job is running works fine but with my **job.service.consul** do not work.
As decribe in **application.properties** using ip or host works but service name does'nt work
Can you help me ?

Application.properties

```
    #Enable ddl
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
##Works
    #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.3.52.121:5432/postgres
    #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://vmc####26.dev.##.##.##.##.##:5432/postgres

##DON'T WORK WITH SERVICE NAME
    #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://pgsql-##.service.consul:5432/postgres
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVICE_NAME}:5432/postgres
    spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER}
    spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Postgresql job

```
job "pgsql-qa" {
  datacenters = ["###"]
  type = "service"


  vault {
          policies = ["###"]
          change_mode = "noop"
          }

  group "pgsql-qa" {
    count = 1

    task "pgsql-qa" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "postgres"
        volumes = [
          "name=####pgsqldb,io_priority=high,size=5,repl=1:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
          ]
        volume_driver = "pxd"

        network_mode = "bridge"
        port_map {
          db = 5432
        }

      }
                        template {
                                data = <<EOH
POSTGRES_USER="{{ with secret "app/###/###/db/admin" }}{{ .Data.data.user }}{{end}}"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="{{ with secret "app/###/###/db/admin" }}{{ .Data.data.password }}{{end}}"

EOH
                                destination = "secrets/db"
                                env = true
                        }



      logs {
        max_files     = 5
        max_file_size = 15
      }

      resources {
        cpu = 1000
        memory = 1024
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port  "db"  {
            static = 5432
          }
        }
      }
      service {
        name = "pgsql-qa"
        tags = ["urlprefix-pgsqlqadb proto=tcp"]
        port = "db"



        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "tcp"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "2s"
          port = "db"
        }
      }

    }
    restart {
      attempts = 10
      interval = "5m"
      delay = "25s"
      mode = "delay"
    }

  }

  update {
    max_parallel = 1
    min_healthy_time = "5s"
    healthy_deadline = "3m"
    auto_revert = false
    canary = 0
  }
}
```

[image: dig command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Just add this line in template {} section to get the IP and the random port created by Nomad.
**db_service_name** change this line with your service name.

```
MY_DB = "{{ range service "${db_service_name}" }}{{ .Address }}:{{ .Port }}{{ end }}"
```

Thx